# What is the URL to execute taxonomy-$taxonomy.php Template

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a WordPress Website www.bccfalna.com and I have created some Custom Taxonomy. Everything is working well when I use following URLs in my web browser:

**domain.tld/Texonomy/Term/**

which is equal to :

*taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php*

Format specified at WordPress Documentation. But I am very confused about What URL I use in my Web Browser, so that I can use following URL specified at WordPress Documentation:

**taxonomy-$taxonomy.php**

I mean, I have created a Template *taxonomy-$taxonomy.php*, But I don't know about What URL I use in my web browser, so that WordPress can run  taxonomy-$taxonomy.php Template and I could see the Output.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php` template applied to term archives, do not create individual `taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php` files. From the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display), this is the hierarchy:

```
taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php
taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php
taxonomy.php
archive.php
index.php
```

Note: in WP, 'general' taxonomy archives (i.e. an archive page showing all posts using terms belonging to a certain taxonomy) are not available out of the box, compare `example.com/tag/` or `example.com/category/`.

PS: You can use [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/reveal-template/) during development to reveal templates being used.